# C# MVC 4: Create Word Document and download without saving in disk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, ms-word

This probably has a very simple answer but i just can't find it.

I have a project using C# MVC 4 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 12

In an action I try to dynamically create a Word file (using a database for the information) and then i want to download it. The file does not exist (it is created from scratch) and I don't want to save it in disk (it does not need to be saved because its content is dynamic).

This is the code for now:

```
public ActionResult Generar(Documento documento)
{
    Application word = new Application();
    word.Visible = false;

    object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Document doc = word.Documents.Add(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

    Paragraph par = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref miss);
    object style = "Heading 1";
    par.Range.set_Style(ref style);
    par.Range.Text = "This is a dummy test";

    byte[] bytes = null;  // This is the part i need to get the bytes of the doc object
    doc.Close();

    word.Quit();

    return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", "NewFile.docx");
}
```

Comment: Instead, use one of various C# libraries that implement the DOCX format.

Comment: You should save it to the disk.  Word is file-based, so you're life is going to be far easier if you just create a temporary file.  As others have mentioned, Word is not really designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: Does anyone of you have a better solution? Because i can not think of what kind of problems i could have with this approach and saving the file i still think is unnecessary.

Comment: A better solution is here: http://docx.codeplex.com/

Comment: Check this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-C-Sharp/ it's using Microsoft.Office.Interop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the library that Robert Harvey recommended DocX.dll (thank you, gentleman), this would be the solution:

```
using Novacode;
using System.Drawing;

.
.
.

public ActionResult Generar(Documento documento)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    DocX doc = DocX.Create(stream);

    Paragraph par = doc.InsertParagraph();
    par.Append("This is a dummy test").Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman")).FontSize(32).Color(Color.Blue).Bold();

    doc.Save();

    return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", "FileName.docx");
}
```

I couldn't find the solution using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word (something so simple, i'm disappointed).

Thank you again to Robert and hope this example helps you solve the problem.

Comment: I was also looking for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word solution to do this same. :(